# Deprecated: mysql_query()

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, mysqli

i just update my server. it showing an error today

> Deprecated: mysql_query(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the >future: use mysqli or PDO instead in C:\wamp\www\work\db\dbfields - Copy.php on line 33

my  dbfields - Copy.php page is

> > #### mysql_query("insert into user(name,address) values('$name','$address')");

i create 2 columns (name&address), need to insert the value of var($name& $address).

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: Everything is answered in the error. The MySQL extension is deprecated. Go read up on PDO and MySQLi

Answer (score 4):

`mysqli_query` is now used instead of `mysql_query`. You can also use `PDO::query` or `MySQLi::query`. You can see the documentation [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)

Answer (score 1):

Read : [The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13944956/the-mysql-extension-is-deprecated-and-will-be-removed-in-the-future-use-mysqli)

It basically means `mysql_query()` can no longer be used. You will have to switch to using PDO.

For PDO, read: http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php